# Get application.yml infos in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have add some config inside my `application.yml` file and I want to read it from my Java code.

The added node inside the YAML file looks like this:

```
myConfig:
    projectOne:
        mantisID: 501
        user: username
        password: passwd
    projectTwo:
        mantisID: 502
        user: username
        password: passwd
```

What I want is to get a List of Project objects where

```
Project.mantisID = 501,
Project.user = "username",
Project.password = "passwd",
```

etc...

I know spring can read this file with some @Value annotation but how can I use this in order to get what I need?

Comment: I don't see any code in the YAML file, there are only scalars and mappings. Are you asking how to rewrite the YAML file? If not then the [tag:yaml] is inappropriately applied

Comment: I meant "node", "mapping". I don't know the correct word. I meant element.

Comment: Elements in YAML only occur in sequences, you don't have any elements in your YAML. If you don't know the correct YAML terminology (which often happens if you only use one language/parser) then at least prefix names by your language ( `Java node` ). And as you noticed you wrote something wrong, please make the question more useful for future readers by editing and correcting it. **Your** problem might be solved, but we are trying to build a quality Q&A site here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to map your configuration to a `Bean`, then you'll be able to inject your `Bean` anywhere and fetch those properties.

To do so, first create a class which represents the data structure in your configuration. Then annotate it with `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Configuration` annotations.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyConfig {

    private final Map<String, Project> myConfig = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Project> getMyConfig() {
        return myConfig;
    }

    public static class Project {

        private String mantisID;
        private String password;
        private String user;

        // Getters and setters...
    }
}
```

**Note** that getters and setters are required in the `Project` class. Also keep in mind that naming of getters and setters is important here.

After you have setup this class, you can inject it anywhere in your project and access its properties.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    private final Map<String, MyConfig.Project> projects;

    @Autowired
    public SomeService(MyConfig config) {
        this.projects = config.getMyConfig();

        projects.get("projectOne").getMantisID();
        projects.get("projectTwo").getPassword();
    }
}
```

You can read more about this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot for the answer. I was on the online resource you provide but wasn't really able to guess my way out of this ^^.

I have another question, how do I do if I want the project list inside a foreach. Imagine my user adds a "projectThree" inside the .yml file.
I need to automatically fetch all projects child of myConfig: entry.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you can fetch all map values by using `.values()` or `.entrySet()` method and iterate them, e.g. `projects.values().forEach(p -> { /* Do something with your project. */ });`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish, I answered myself to my second question.
This is what my service looks like now :

```
@Service
public class MantisProjectService {

    private final Map<String, MantisProjectConfiguration.Project> projects;

    private List<MantisProjectConfiguration.Project> mantisProjects = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    public MantisProjectService(MantisProjectConfiguration mantisProjectConfiguration)
    {
        this.projects = mantisProjectConfiguration.getMantisProjectConfiguration();

        for (Map.Entry<String, MantisProjectConfiguration.Project> project : projects.entrySet())
        {
            MantisProjectConfiguration.Project mantisProject = project.getValue();
            mantisProject.setName(project.getKey());
            mantisProjects.add(mantisProject);
        }
    }

    public List<MantisProjectConfiguration.Project> getMantisProjects()
    {
        return mantisProjects;
    }

}
```

It returns a List of all the projects. And it is awesome! =)